# readdir()->d_name giving weird values

Tags: c, readdir

I am trying to get the name of the parent directory by using this code:

```
dirp=opendir(cur_spot);
printf("parent name: %s\n", readdir(dirp)->d_name);
closedir(dirp);
```

cur_spot holds '..'.

i do this in a loop and it keeps climbing up the directories to the root, the sequence of my output it:

```
.
.bash_logout
.
.
srv
```

I know that it is traversing correctly because i am checking the inodes along the way.

Do i need to use something different than d_name?

Thanks

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee what order readdir will return the dir entries in. So expected '.' or '..' to be first is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this based on the ideas in the comments under sjs' answer:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int LookupName(const char* parent, ino_t ino, char *name, size_t size)
{
  DIR *dp = opendir(parent);
  if (!dp) return -1;

  int ret = -1;
  struct dirent *de;
  while (de = readdir(dp))
  {
    if (de->d_ino == ino)
    {
      strncpy(name, de->d_name, size);
      ret = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  closedir(dp);
  if (ret == -1) errno = ENOENT;
  return ret;
}

int GetWorkdir(char *workdir, size_t size)
{
  struct stat st;
  if (stat(".", &st)) return -1;

  char path[PATH_MAX];
  strncpy(path, "..", sizeof(path));

  memset(workdir, '\0', sizeof(workdir));

  char name[PATH_MAX];
  while (1)
  {
    if (LookupName(path, st.st_ino, name, sizeof(name))) return -1;
    if (!strcmp(name, "..") || !strcmp(name, "."))
    {
      strncpy(name, "/", sizeof(name));
      strncat(name, workdir, sizeof(name));
      strncpy(workdir, name, size);
      break;
    }

    if (workdir[0] != '\0')
    {
      strncat(name, "/", sizeof(name));
    }

    strncat(name, workdir, sizeof(name));
    strncpy(workdir, name, size);

    if (stat(path, &st)) return -1;

    strncat(path, "/..", sizeof(path));
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char workDir[PATH_MAX];

  assert(!GetWorkdir(workDir, sizeof(workDir)));
  printf("%s\n", workDir);
}
```

Comment: im getting: a.out: pwd1.c:73: main: Assertion `!GetWorkdir(workDir, sizeof(workDir))' failed.
Aborted

Comment: took the ! out of the assert and now it is working, but there is './' repeated about 600 times before the actual pwd

Comment: yeah, i can't even find a place that would be adding './' to it over and over

Comment: Maybe lookup name is returning '.', did you test it since caf made an update adding the additional check?

Answer (score 0):

`readdir` is reading the directory, so when you say

```
printf("parent name: %s\n", readdir(dirp)->d_name);
```

you are actually asking to have the name of the first entry inside `..` printed for you, not the name of the `..` directory.

Depending on what you are trying to do, perhaps parsing the output of `getcwd` might be a better approach?

Comment: unfortunately i am essentially trying to implement getcwd without using it

Comment: @TroyCosentino Ah, ok. Thinking off the top of my head here. How about if you use `readdir` to get the inode number of the current directory (i.e. `.`) then open the parent directory, `..`, and search until you find an item with the same inode number. Then you will have the basename of the current working directory and you can repeat this process to get the names of the parents.

Comment: sorry, trying to follow what you said.. So i currently am doing what you outlined, i keep adding '/..' to what i am checking so that it keeps climbing until i find where the parent inode and the current inode are the same, meaning it is the root. From there how could i convert inode to the correct name? or how does this give me a basename?

Comment: figured it out, think im going to keep track of the inodes as i traverse up and then going back down i can check if they match.. should work like a charm

Comment: @TroyCosentino Sounds like you've got it, but just to clarify what I was saying: Start by calling `opendir` on `.`. Repeatedly call `readdir` until you get an item with the name `.`. Now you have the inode number for the current directory. Next call `opendir` on `..`. Repeatedly call `readdir` until you find the item with the inode number you found earlier. Now you have the name of the current directory. Repeat this process to get the name of the parent directory... and so on until you have the name of every parent directory up to the root of the filesystem.